# how to send form data with submit to bootstrap modal

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, form-submit

i have a form and I need to send value to bootstrap modal in this page.
now i don't know how to type `action=""` or modal or submit.
thanks.

```
<form action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="sirdash">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="azari">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>write some code html and php and use form post firstname and lastname in this area</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```